# How to add an additional static IP to an otherwise DHCP enabled windows box

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

Is it possible at all?

I mean, obviously DHCP + static alias is not working. I am looking for a workaround, like adding an interface and binding the static IP to that.

Is it doable somehow?

Comment: I don't think so that windows can have 2 simultaneous ip adresses on one interface... with one exception ipv4 and ipv6 address

Comment: @Tomas of course windows can have two address on the same interface - but they both have to be static

Comment: It is (now) possible with newer versions of Windows 10, see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/679134/14517) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can easily add additional IPs to Windows boxes (Go to IPv4 Properties > Advanced, then click Add on IP addresses), however, this option is disabled automatically when DHCP is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* possible. Install an instance of the Microsoft Loopback network adapter, and use it as an alias interface.
[technet howto](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/259c7ef2-3770-4212-8fca-c58936979851/how-to-install-microsoft-loopback-adapter?forum=w7itpronetworking)

Then configure it just like you would a regular NIC.