# How to assign a secondary IP to a network interface in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, ip

In Windows 10 in a system with a single network adapter, I need to assign a secondary IP to the adapter in a different range, while the primary IP is obtained via DHCP. I'm not going to assign the primary IP manually, because I don't want to get conflict in the future. The primary address is not important what to be, it just connects the system to the network. But I need to address the system via the secondary static IP.
What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a static IP alias to a DHCP interface on Windows 8 (and above)](https://superuser.com/questions/679134/add-a-static-ip-alias-to-a-dhcp-interface-on-windows-8-and-above)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I examined it, but got disconnected! I used DHCP again and it assigned a new ip! Anyway, have to use another system, or maybe a virtual one for this purpose, because the system physical access is not easy and it took some time for me to do the operation. Going to examine the method on a virtual system and see what will happen. Thanks